# What is Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial Site Programmed In?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Kind of a silly question, but, as someone learning Rails (after mucking around in PHP for several years), with the intent of building some serious apps but also doing content management, I'm curious what a simple content-managed site like that one runs on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/) website is a Rails 2.3 app running on [Heroku](http://heroku.com/). (At some point I plan to upgrade it to Rails 3, but this isn't currently a priority.) Because the content is largely static, most pages are cached using [Heroku's Varnish HTTP cache](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching).

Answer (score 8):

BuiltWith Technology Profiler Extension for Chrome will show you... I use this plugin all the time to answer similar questions of curiousity.

ruby.railstutorial.org

Varnish

Varnish is a web accelerator / reverse proxy caching server.

nginx

nginx [engine x] is a HTTP server and mail proxy server written by Igor Sysoev.
Frameworks

Ruby on Rails Token

Ruby on Rails is an open-source web framework that is optimized for programmer happiness and sustainable productivity. Note that Ruby on Rails has two detection techniques and this is one of them.

Ruby on Rails

Ruby on Rails is an open-source web framework that is optimized for programmer happiness and sustainable productivity.

Comment: Thanks; I apologize for not being more specific: I did check using BuiltWith, and saw this.  I guess I meant more narrowly, is the site running on a third-party Rails-based CMS?  Is it just html in a database being pulled by a very simple Rails app?  I'm trying to learn how one ideologically goes about building a site like that after one is a Rails guru.